# Mock an abstract class having no public constructors using MS Fakes

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes

I am trying to mock abstract classes having no public constructors like e.g. ToolStripItem residing in Systems.Windows.Forms namespace. The problem is that the Shim class that is generated by MS Fakes for an abstract class above has a single constructor with a single parameter where the instance of the abstract class has to be provided. In the case of ToolStripItem this constructor is like that:

```
public ShimToolStripItem(ToolStripItem instance)
```

What could I provide as the value of instance parameter in order to be able to effectively mock methods and properties of ToolStripItem, given the fact that in the assembly I am testing there are not any classes inheriting from ToolStripItem ?

Trying to pass null as the value of instance parameter fails with an exception occurring inside the shim code. So obviously this is not supported.

Creating a test class that will inherit from the abstract class and implementing whatever is needed, will work, but I would like a more generic solution.

Comment: `ToolStripItem` has a `protected` constructor. Have you considered writing an actual class that inherits from `ToolStripItem`?

Comment: @mjwills Yes and it did work, but as I also mention in the question above I would like a more generic / less hustle solution that will be applicable to all abstract classes.

Comment: Do you specifically want to use Fakes? Would you be open to use other mocking libraries?

Comment: Fakes would be the preferable solution, but I am also open to other mocking frameworks as soon as this feature is provided free by them